# Visual Studio 2010: Unit test results with "jump to file at line/col" links

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, format, message

I'm unit testing a compiler and would like to provide a unit test result that can be clicked and will bring visual studio to a specified test input file with the cursor at a specified line/col. Is this possible?

I've tried the format outlined at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/11/03/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats.aspx

For example:

Main.cs(17,20): warning CS0168: The variable 'foo' is declared but never used

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Visual studio doesn't do columns. I have built my own VS error formatter and the sytex goes like this:

```
%file%(%line%): error %specific error%: %error text%
```

That appears to work fine for VS 2008 and 2010.

The link you provided has more details that you can use to format your error or warning string.